# can anyone see why this javascript function isn't working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

can anyone see what my error is? I am trying to invert the property key and value

```js
function invert(object) {
    let invertedObject = {};
    for(let key in object) {
        const originalValue = key[object]
        invertedObject = {originalValue : key}
    }
    return invertedObject;
}

const myObject = {House : 'London'}

const result = invert(myObject)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Not key[object] -> object[key]

Comment: `invertedObject = {` <-- logic error

Answer (score 3):

You've got two problems in your code:

```
const originalValue = key[object]
invertedObject = {originalValue : key}
```

You are calling `key[object]` instead of `object[key]`, and you are setting the key name `originalValue` instead of using the value for the key name. Should look like this:

```
let originalValue = object[key];
invertedObject[originalValue] = key;
```

```js
function invert(object) {
    let invertedObject = {};
    for(let key in object) {
        let originalValue = object[key];
        invertedObject[originalValue] = key;
    }
    return invertedObject;
}

const myObject = {House : 'London'}

const result = invert(myObject)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This answer actually describes what the problem is instead of just giving the solution.

Comment: this is great. thank you all very much!!!

Comment: you still able to use originalValue as dynamic key, but you need to wrap it in square brackets: invertedObject = {[originalValue]: key} to indicate that it's a variable, not a straight key

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following changes needs to be applied in order to fix your code:

```js
function invert(object) {
    let invertedObject = {};
    for(let key in object) {
        const originalValue = object[key]
        invertedObject = {[originalValue] : key}
    }
    return invertedObject;
}

const myObject = {House : 'London'}
const result = invert(myObject)

console.log(result); // {'London': 'House'}
```

However, it looks like your original function will only work for single object entry, if you would like to apply to all keys, I would suggest to rewrite it as:

```js
function invert(object) {
    let invertedObject = {};
    for(let key in object) {
        const originalValue = object[key]
        invertedObject[originalValue] = key
    }
    return invertedObject;
}

const myObject = {'House' : 'London', 'World': 'Hello', 'Cool': 'You'}
const result = invert(myObject)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: added enhanced example to make sure we cover all object entries, not only single